# How to solve the given Premises using quantifiers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

I have a question that

[image]

[image]

I have tried as but i am not getting the actual one. I tried by chaging the consequent formula to ( or ) formula. Still The premise 2 is not equal as the consequent of premise 1. What I am thinking is ,I tried by changing the consequent to negation , but the (not W(y)) is not getting for me.
Can anyone tried to solve this.Please.

Comment: What proof system are you using : Natural Deduction, Tableau, Resolution, Logical Equivalences,...?

Comment: Its a  Inference theory of predicate calculus concept

Comment: NO; in 2 and 3 you cannotv"instantiate the formulae in that way...

Comment: In 2 and 3 i have used universal specification and existential specification

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

Try by contradiction, assuming the negation of the conclusion :

> $\lnot (\forall x)(Px \to \lnot Qx)$.

It is equivalent to :

> $(\exists x)(Px \land Qx)$.

Now with this we can apply *modus ponens* to 1st premise to derive : $ (\forall y)(My \to Wy)$ and this will give us a contradiction with the 2nd premise :  $(\exists y)(My \land \lnot Wy)$.

Comment: Once see my edited post..I have added my solution. I got struck at 6th..

Answer (score 0):

More hints:

line 2: you can't do existential specification on 1,  since 1 is not an existential ... It is a conditional whose antecedent is an existential. So it looks like an existential sicne the first symbol is $\exists$, but it really is not. Its main connective is the $\rightarrow$. So, if you want to use 1, you will probably at some point have to get the antecedent (the existential!) so you can do Modus Ponens.

Line 3: Likewise you can't do universal specification on 2, since 2 is not a universal statement. This is a lot easier to see, since the universal is in the middle of the statement. As a general rule, you can *never* do any specification of any quantifier that occurs somewhere in the middle of a statement!